# HomeKit Develop: addUser funcion deprecated in iOS 10. How to add user?

Tags: ios, homekit

I would like to enable my Homekit App to add another user. I though I could use function `addUser`but according to link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhome/1620213-adduser

some user-related functions had deprecated. Is there any alternate function for `addUser`? How can I add user in Homekit app in iOS 10?

Thanks!!!

[image]

The error description is `Optional("Operation is not supported.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the latest functions you can use. Doesn't look like they really replaced it with anything. I am assuming because of security reasons.

Users now have to add other users from their HomeKit. Developers do not have the right anymore.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhome

Comment: Thank you! But I can add another user from Apple's own Home App. Doesn't it mean that only Apple itself can add another user but other developers cannot?

Comment: Correct, it has to be done within the HomeKit App by the primary user. Cant do it outside of their HomeKit app anymore.

Comment: hmmmmmm it sounds bad. Your answer is helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I didn't have a solution hope you find a way around it!

Comment: That's fine. Thank you all the same. I hope someone else can see this problem and provide a better solution.